# Delayed Job in Rails 4 with Capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano, delayed-job

I cant figure how to start Delayed Jobs on a dedicated Ubuntu server.

It works fine on my localhost but when I run on my server

```
sudo RAILS_ENV=production bin/delayed_job restart
```

I get

```
sudo: bin/delayed_job: command not found
```

On top of that, if I run the "rake jobs:work RAILS_ENV=production" command Im getting the following error:

```
 PG::FeatureNotSupported: ERROR:  SELECT FOR UPDATE/SHARE is not allowed in subqueries
```

Apparently theres an issue with my psql version.

Is there any way I can get the script to work? Any effective Capistrano recipes available? All ive found on the web are old recipes for Rails 3 and older versions of capistrano.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

I have already bundled install the daemons gem and generated "delayed_job:active_record" on my local machine, then proceded to cap deploy which bundle installed and migrated in the production server.

The bin/delayed_job file exists in the server yet it fails with command not found.

Comment: Are you sure you installed the gems at your server? bundle install ?

Comment: Plz make sure to add gem "daemons" to your Gemfile, then bundle install. You have to run rails generate delayed_job:active_record &&
rake db:migrate.

Comment: @EkiEqbal Yes I have already bundled install the daemons gem and generated "delayed_job:active_record" on my local machine. Do I have to run it on the production server also?

Comment: Ya please run it at your production server, or if you want create a Capistrano recipe to automate that at the production server.

Comment: Keep me updated so I can post it as an answer if your problem has been solved.

Comment: @EkiEqbal Thank you Eki, ive tried running it on the production server but it keeps throwing me an error. " FATAL:  database "lafunda_development" does not exist (PG::ConnectionBad)" Apparently its searching for my development Database? I tried using RAILS_ENV=production in the command but no luck - when I run rails console and ask for the Rails.env it returns "production"

Comment: Run the rake tasks like following: bundle exec rails generate delayed_job:active_record & bundle exec rake db:migrate. And please share the error.

Comment: The error is the same: /var/www/apps/lafunda/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:848:in `initialize': FATAL:  database "lafunda_development" does not exist (PG::ConnectionBad)

Comment: I think I know what is going on. In your production server, first, try *RAILS_ENV=test rake db:create* && "RAILS_ENV=test rake db:migrate". One you do that, run *RAILS_ENV=test rails generate delayed_job:active_record && RAILS_ENV=test rake db:migrate*. Let me know

Comment: My bad. Change RAILS_ENV=test to RAILS_ENV=production :)

Comment: And add this to config/environment.rb: ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'production'.

Comment: @EkiEqbal Funny that worked!! Yet after running "RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job start" the pending jobs are not getting done.

Comment: Nevermind after I deployed with capistrano I cant call the script anymore.

Comment: What type of errors you are getting using Capistrano.

Comment: Try to add something like run "cd #{current_path}; #{sudo} RACK_ENV=production bundle exec #{current_path}/bin/delayed_job start"
to your deploy.rb file.

Answer (score 0):

And add this to config/environment.rb:

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'production'
```

Then at your production server:

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake db:migrate 

RAILS_ENV=test production generate delayed_job:active_record && RAILS_ENV=production rake db:migrate
```

Now after you do that:

```
RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job start
```

As for Capistrano error you are facing, please try to add the command like:

```
run "cd #{current_path}; #{sudo} RACK_ENV=production bundle exec #{current_path}/bin/delayed_job start"
```

Answer (score 0):

You must run this on target server:

```
bundle exec rails generate delayed_job
```